# Oracle Query to fetch right rows base on my

Tags: sql, oracle

I have sample date like below. I need to pick up the specific values (i.e) if column type values "st/cm" are similar to type column values "s/p" for columns id,name and value, then pick "s/p" rows as shown below

```
id   name  text  value  type   date type 
123  tan   abc   98     st     2017-06-09  
123  tan   abc   98     st     2017-06-09 
123  tan   a     98     s      2017-06-09 --pick this
123  tan   a     98     s      2017-06-09 --pick this
124  pan   ndc   97     cm     2017-06-09  
124  pan   ndc   97     cm     2017-06-09 
124  pan   b     97     p      2017-06-09 --pick this
124  pan   b     97     p      2017-06-09 --pick this
```

Expected Output:here the below columns are similar for type "ST/CM" compared to   "S/P" rows, so we pick "S/P" rows

```
    id   name  value  type   date type 
    123  tan    98     st     2017-06-09  
    123  tan    98     st     2017-06-09 
    123  tan    98     s      2017-06-09 --pick this
    123  tan    98     s      2017-06-09 --pick this
    124  pan    97     cm     2017-06-09  
    124  pan    97     cm     2017-06-09 
    124  pan    97     p      2017-06-09 --pick this
    124  pan    97     p      2017-06-09 --pick this
```

Comment: there is a logic ..  ???  try explain better  .. your question ...what mean "are similar"  ?? why  some row and not others ??

Comment: @scaisEdge so basically the logic is as below "If column TYPE values "st/cm" are similar to "s/p" for columns id,name and value, then pick "s/p"

Comment: can you define 'similar'? is it exactly same or is it like since 's' is there in 'st' you consider both similar ?

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my post to clarify this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for all `s` / `p` rows that have at least two `st` / `cm` rows with the same identifiers, you could just use `count()`:

```
SELECT date_type from mytable t1 WHERE t1.type in ('s', 'p') AND 
    (SELECT count(*) from mytable t2 where t2.id = t1.id and t2.name = t1.name 
     and t2.value = t1.value and t2.type = DECODE(t1.type, 's', 'st', 'p', 'cm')) > 1;
```

or, if it's enough to have a single match, you can use `EXISTS()`

```
SELECT date_type from mytable t1 WHERE t1.type in ('s', 'p') AND 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 from mytable t2 where t2.id = t1.id and t2.name = t1.name 
     and t2.value = t1.value and t2.type = DECODE(t1.type, 's', 'st', 'p', 'cm'));
```